# How to get width and height of the bounding box of a rotated rectangle

Tags: math, geometry, trigonometry

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Calculate Bounding box coordinates from a rotated rectangle, Picture inside](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/622140/calculate-bounding-box-coordinates-from-a-rotated-rectangle-picture-inside)
>   [AABB of rotated sprite?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6657479/aabb-of-rotated-sprite)

I have a rectangle with a width of w and height of h. I rotate the rectangle r degrees(originating at its center point).

How can I determine the width(w2) and height(h2) of the bounding box after the rotation.

[image]

Comment: I don't think it is a duplicate because I don't have any coordinates of the rectangle and I am not looking for the min and max of the bounding box. I am looking for the width and height.

Comment: `width = max_x - min_x` and `height = max_y - min_y`. No?

Comment: Correct but I think its irrelevant since I don't know min_x,max_x,min_y,max_y. And I don't believe it could be calculated with the information that is given. But I think the width and height could be calculated directly somehow, I just don't know how.

Comment: Might be more appropriate on math.stackexchange.com

Comment: Dan W is correct, I ended up finding the answer on math.stackexchange. Also it turns out Gareth is correct too that this is a duplicate of the question he linked to and the answer is provided there.

Comment: Does this question belong here? How do you relate it to programming?